# Realm (Swift): How to get at MutableSet data during migration?

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I've got a local Realm (using the RealmSwift API version 10.15.1) that has a `Player` object that I'm trying to migrate.  The `Player` currently contains field called `preferredPositions` that is a `MutableSet<PositionClass>`. The definition of `Player` looks like this:

```
@objc final class Player: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var playerId: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var preferredPositions: MutableSet<PositionClass> = MutableSet<PositionClass>()
    ...
}
```

and `PositionClass` looks like this:

```
class PositionClass: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var positionClassId: String = ""
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var order: Int = 0
    @Persisted var abbreviation: String = ""
    ...
}
```

I want to do a migration that will change `preferredPositions` from a `MutableSet<PositionClass>` to a `List<PositionClass>` since now I want `preferredPositions` to be ordered.

So the new `Player` looks like:

```
@objc final class Player: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var playerId: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var preferredPositions: List<PositionClass> = List<PositionClass>()
    ...
}
```

However, I can't figure out the magic incantation in the migration configuration to get access to the `preferredPositions` data.

In my migration I have:

```
    let schemaVersion: UInt64 = 22
    let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
                                    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        ...
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 22) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Player.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                if let preferredPositionsSet: MutableSet<PositionClass> = oldObject!["preferredPositions"] as? MutableSet<PositionClass> {
                    let preferredPositionsList: List<PositionClass> = List()
                    preferredPositionsSet.forEach { (positionClass: PositionClass) in
                        preferredPositionsList.append(positionClass)
                    }
                    newObject!["preferredPositions"] = preferredPositionsList
                } else {
                    NSLog("preferredPositionsSet is nil.")
                }
            }
        }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

But the line

```
let preferredPositionsSet: MutableSet<PositionClass> = oldObject!["preferredPositions"] as? MutableSet<PositionClass>
```

always returns nil.  I've looked in the debugger and it seems like `oldObject!["preferredPositions"]` is a `MutableSet<PositionClass>`.  For example if I add the code:

```
    let preferredPositionsAny = oldObject!["preferredPositions"]
```

and then look at `preferredPositionsAny` in the debugger it shows:

[image: debugger showing type]

So, the underlying type is correct, but I don't know how to get at it properly.

Or am I supposed to do the migration in a different way?

Comment: Nothing really jumps out at me being 'wrong'. What happens if you do this `let preferredPositionsAny = oldObject!["preferredPositions"]` and then `print(preferredPositionsAny)` and/or iterate over the set. Is the data you want printing to console? I am trying to verify the data is actually available and not nil.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, it shows that it is a `Realm.Swift.MutableSet<RealmSwift.DynamicObject`, and then the underlying is a `MutableSet<PositionClass>`, so yeah, the data is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code TL;DR:**

```
    let schemaVersion: UInt64 = 22
    let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
                                    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        ...
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 22) {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Player.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                let newRealm = newObject!.realm
                let preferredPositionsList: List<PositionClass> = List()
                let preferredPositionsSet = oldObject!.dynamicMutableSet("preferredPositions")
                preferredPositionsSet.forEach { positionClass in
                    if let newPositionClass = newRealm?.object(ofType: PositionClass.self, forPrimaryKey: positionClass["positionClassId"]) {
                        preferredPositionsList.append(newPositionClass)
                    }
                }
                newObject!["preferredPositions"] = preferredPositionsList
            }
        }
```

**More Complete Answer:**

There were a couple of things I was getting wrong:

1. the data type for the "old" object isn't a `MutableSet<PositionClass>`, but a `MutableSet<DynamicObject>`.  This was why the cast to `MutableSet<PositionClass>` was always returning `nil`.
2. There's also a clearer way to fetch the old `MutableSet`, so instead of calling

```
let preferredPositionsSet = oldObject!["preferredPositions"] as! MutableSet<DynamicObject>
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37588630/1204250 I found

```
let preferredPositionsSet = oldObject!.dynamicMutableSet("preferredPositions")
```

Which seems to have the return the same object, but again, a bit more clear

3. From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37588630/1204250, to re-populate the new `List` with the existing `PositionClass` instances (instead of creating new ones), you need to fetch the data from the Realm.  However in order to get a parameter to fetch the data. Since the "old" `MutableSet` contains `DynamicObject`, you need to access it using the DynamicObject method of named fields e.g. `positionClass["positionClassId"]` instead of accessing a property on the actual base object type e.g. `positionClass.positionClassId`. So that's where

```
let newRealm = newObject!.realm
if let newPositionClass = newRealm?.object(ofType: PositionClass.self, forPrimaryKey: positionClass["positionClassId"]) {
...
```

comes from.

Comment: Very interesting find. When I try to use`dynamicMutableSet`, XCode flags that line with the following error `Value of type 'MigrationObject' (aka 'DynamicObject') has no member 'dynamicMutableSet'`. What version of Realm are you using as I cannot find that parameter in the docs at all.

Comment: Hmm..  I'm on 10.15.1.  I'll likely update to latest shortly.

Comment: @Jay I just updated to 10.17.0 and it still works for me.